# Traversing down keys in a dictionary to get a value from known keys

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, object> testJson` that looks like this:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Request": {
      "Id": "ADLFKJ9LKJADFJLSKLDJFAS",
      "Ts": "Fri Apr 04 10:51:54 EDT 2014",
      "Parameters": "advertisers=&responseFormat=json"
    },
    "Response": {
      "Id": null,
      "Ts": null
    },
    "StatusCode": "09",
    "Message": "Processing."
  }
}
```

I need to get the values for `Data` ==> `Request` ==> `Id` and `Data` ==> `StatusCode` and `Data` ==> `Message`.

So far, I have

```
var requestId = (from p in testJson
                             where p.Key.Contains("Id")
                             select p.Value)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(requestId.ToString());
```

It doesn't seem to be working the way I expect...  `requestId` is returning `null`.

Thanks.

Comment: How does deserializing the JSON into a dictionary of <string, object> preserve the object graph?

Comment: Can you give an example of what is the key and what is the value. It looks like you only shows the value and not the key.

Comment: @AlexSiepman Id is the key, ADLFKJ9LKJADFJLSKLDJFAS is the value.  I want the *value* ADLFKJ9LKJADFJLSKLDJFAS stored into requestId.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the nested JSON elements are also of type `Dictionary<string, object>`...

```
var data = (Dictionary<string, object>)testJson["Data"];
var request = (Dictionary<string, object>)testJson["Request"];

var message = (string)data["Message"];
var status code = (string)data["StatusCode"];
var id = (string)request["Id"];
```

Comment: should day data not date